# Is it possible to sort a mongodb array of subdocuments straight with pymongo?

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, sorting

I don't need to sort the returned documents (objects) but an array each of them based on a nested value.Is it something doable with pymongo.sort()?

Assuming an object is:

```
{ //document data,
  array : [ {//subdocument data,
             "key" : 185},
             {//subdocument data,
             "key" : 186},
             {...}]
}
```

I have tried the following which does not work but I search for a simple similar option:

```
db.col.find().sort('array.key', pymongo.ASCENDING)
```

or should I do it with python sort?

```
for location in locations:
    data['array'] = sorted(data['array'], key=lambda x: x['key'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but currently this is not possible with Mongo.

So your only resort is to sort this in your application layer, which you are doing successfully.
Note that if you always want your results to be sorted, you can achieve this by using [$sort in your $push operator.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) In your case you would do something like this:

```
db.coll.update(
  { _id : ID },
  { 
     $push: {
       array: {
          $each: [{ key: 13}],
          $sort: { key: 1 }
       }
     }
  })
```

This way after any update your subdocument will be sorted. And then when you retrieve it you will not need to sort it.

Comment: Thanks. When I update I use `$addToSet` to add some safety instead of `$push`. I read the documentation and I think it's not possible to use `$sort` with `$addToSet` yet, right?

Comment: yes, because sets are not ordered. Only in lists (with $push you can do sort)